# How can I enable the change log collapsible field on adding new contacts?

Tags: logs

I have seen this field before, but suddenly it disappeared and there is nowhere I can find to enable it, it's a collapsible field that allows you to select with a radio button the date created and date modified.

Even if I have it selected in display preferences, it's still not displaying. Tried to add a custom field for it to no avail...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Logging turned on/off at /civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1

Comment: Tried that to no avail...;(

Comment: When I enable logs, the field still doesn't show up and ...as an added bonus, creates and additional error: x
Access Denied
Ensure you are still logged in and have permission to access this feature.

Comment: Error is this one:  Type access denied
Date Tuesday, October 9, 2018 - 13:01
User 1
Location http://localhost/crm4/civicrm/report/instance/39?reset=1&force=1&snippet=json&section=2&altered_contact_id_op=eq&altered_contact_id_value=1&cid=1
Referrer http://localhost/crm4/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=1&context=search&key=55d2176b4bdae5f30545ad1731823f1a_2623
Message civicrm/report/instance/39
Severity warning
Hostname ::1
Operations

Comment: okay but a report/instance warning may be unrelated. i would google for that error and if not find anything open a new Question on here about it

Comment: (unrelated but interfering)

Comment: Actually, I think it's impossible to set it up as a field, it's seems it only shows up in search view, not add view, seems like this is being done automatically in the backend when you add contacts, then it only displays on bottom or on search, but not sure!

Comment: i think i now do not understand what you are trying to do. "impossible to set it up as a field" makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 5 years since you asked, but... there is a "View Change Log" link at the footer of contact pages:

[image: Screenshot showing the View Change Log link.]

Your screenshot is from the Advanced Search. If the Change Log section is enabled in the corresponding Display Preferences setting, that section should appear.

Your question mentions "on adding new contacts". No Change Log section is expected in the page to add new contacts. Among other reasons, the contact doesn't exist yet and it has no changes logged. :)